# Count instances of location in two tables, store in two columns in result

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join, count

I have a table of locations, a table of restaurants and a table of casinos, the latter two including the id of their location.

From these tables I want a new table of locations, along with a column counting how many restaurants are at that location, and how many casinos are at that location, unless there are 0 of both, in which case I want to exclude that location from the result.

The following pseudocode query works for me for doing the above with just the restaurants, but I'm having trouble adding the  casinos to this. Any advice on how to accomplish this?

`SELECT r.location_id, l.name, count(r.location_id) FROM restaurants r join locations l ON r.location_id = l.id GROUP BY l.id, l.name;`

Here's example data for the tables I have

```
Locations
 id |  name   | lat_lng  
----+---------+-----------
  1 | Florida | 3A29F3840
  2 | Nevada  | 4G32J1273
  3 | Maine   | 9Y35V9241

Restaurants
 id | location_id | name  
----+-------------+--------------------
  1 |           2 | McDonalds
  2 |           1 | Cheesecake Factory
  3 |           2 | Steak and Shake

Casinos
 id | location_id | name  
----+-------------+-----------------
  1 |           2 | Ballys
  2 |           2 | Treasure Island
```

And an example of the table I'd like to get

```
Result
location_id | location_name | restaurant_count | casino_count  
------------+---------------+------------------+--------------
          1 | Florida       |                1 |            0
          2 | Nevada        |                2 |            2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left Join and group by, count distinct .. anchor on Location

```
SELECT l.id [Location Id], 
l.name [Location Name], 
count(distinct r.id) [Location count],
count(distinct c.id) [Casino Count] 
 FROM locations l
  left join  restaurants r  ON r.location_id = l.id
  left join casinos c on c.location_id = l.id
 GROUP BY l.id,l.name
 having count(distinct r.id)> 0 or
 count(distinct c.id) > 0
```

---

```
/* sample script using SQL-SERVER */


select * 
into #Locations
from (
values( 1, 'Florida', '3A29F3840'),
  (2,'Nevada','4G32J1273'),
  (3,'Maine','9Y35V9241')
 ) 
 as x (id,name,lat_lng)


select * 
into #Restaurants
from (
values( 1,2),
     (2,1),
    (3,2)
 ) 
 as x (id,location_id)

select * 
into #Casinos
from (
values( 1,2),
     (2,2)
    ) 
 as x (id,location_id)


 SELECT l.id [Location Id], 
l.name [Location Name], 
count(distinct r.id) [Location count],
 count(distinct c.id) [Casino Count] 
 FROM #locations l
  left join  #restaurants r  ON r.location_id = l.id
  left join #casinos c on c.location_id = l.id
 GROUP BY l.id,l.name
 having count(distinct r.id)> 0 or
 count(distinct c.id) > 0


 drop table #Locations
 drop table #Restaurants
 drop table #Casinos
```

Result

```
Location Id Location Name Location count Casino Count
----------- ------------- -------------- ------------
1           Florida       1              0
3           Maine         0              0
2           Nevada        2              2
```

Comment: Thank you! Having some issues though. This seems to work whenever there are either restaurants or casinos in the location, but when there are both it gives me a much higher number, e.g. 3300 for both restaurants and casinos when there are really 165 restaurants and 20 casinos, or 4836 when there are 186 restaurants and 26 casinos. It also includes in the results locations with 0 restaurants and 0 casinos, which I would rather not have.

Comment: Just noticed 3300=165*20, 4836=186*26, seems they're getting multiplied

Comment: can you try the updated script again or can you post your script

Comment: Sure, still having the same issues:
`SELECT l.id as "location_id", 
       l.name as "location_name",
       count(r.id) as "restaurant_count", 
       count(c.id) as "casinois_count" 
FROM locations l 
    left join restaurants r ON r.location_id = l.id 
    left join casinos c ON c.location_id = l.id 
GROUP BY l.id,
         l.name
LIMIT 10;`

Comment: Thank you!! The counting works now - is there a way to change it so that it doesn't include Maine (0 restaurants, 0 casinos) in the results?